# Upload image in angular js

Tags: javascript, angularjs, file-upload

I want to upload the image in angular js the image name need to send to db and the uploaded image move to an folder(target location) Same like move_uploaded_file in PHP. I have implemented as below:

```
<input type="file" id="file" name="file" ng-model="machineimage"/>
<button ng-click="uploadMachineImage($index)">Add</button>
```

In controller:

```
$scope.uploadMachineImage = function() {
  var imgobject = document.getElementById('file').files[0];
  console.log(imgobject['name']);
  r = new FileReader();
  r.onloadend = function(e) {
    var data = e.target.result;
    console.log(data);
  }
  r.readAsBinaryString(imgobject);
};
```

Comment: Probably not the answer you want, but I would recommend using [ng-flow](https://flowjs.github.io/ng-flow/). It has made life easy for me.

Comment: The above code i wrote can able to get the data as byte format One thing i need to push the image in a folder